# VSTS - Visual Studio Test Task fails with an error No Test is Available

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET application on VSTS. I am getting an error about **No Test is available** in my RetailerWebsite.UnitTests.dll.

Below are the logs:

`2017-09-22T18:27:57.5945288Z ##[section]Starting: VsTest - testAssemblies
2017-09-22T18:27:57.5945288Z ==============================================================================
2017-09-22T18:27:57.5945288Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2017-09-22T18:27:57.5945288Z Description  : Run tests with Visual Studio test runner
2017-09-22T18:27:57.5945288Z Version      : 2.1.8
2017-09-22T18:27:57.5945288Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-09-22T18:27:57.5945288Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
2017-09-22T18:27:57.5945288Z ==============================================================================
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z ========================================================
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Test assemblies : **\RetailerWebsite.UnitTests.dll,!**\obj\**
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Test filter criteria : null
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Search folder : C:\agent\_work\4\s\src\RetailerWebsite.UnitTests\bin\Release
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Run settings file : C:\agent\_work\4\s
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Run in parallel : false
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Run in isolation : false
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Path to custom adapters : null
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Other console options : /UseVsixExtensions:true
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Code coverage enabled : false
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : 15.0
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z [command]C:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.1.8\vswhere.exe -version [15.0,16.0) -latest -products * -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.TestTools.Core -property installationPath
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z [command]C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\WMIC.exe datafile where "name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TestWindow\\vstest.console.exe'" get Version /Value
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z Version=15.0.26720.2
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:27:59.9381761Z 
2017-09-22T18:28:00.2506608Z ========================================================
2017-09-22T18:28:00.5943958Z [command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" C:\agent\_work\4\s\src\RetailerWebsite.UnitTests\bin\Release\RetailerWebsite.UnitTests.dll /logger:trx /UseVsixExtensions:true
2017-09-22T18:28:00.5943958Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.26720.2
2017-09-22T18:28:00.5943958Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2017-09-22T18:28:00.5943958Z 
2017-09-22T18:28:01.7349947Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2017-09-22T18:28:02.2974670Z Warning: No test is available in C:\agent\_work\4\s\src\RetailerWebsite.UnitTests\bin\Release\RetailerWebsite.UnitTests.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
2017-09-22T18:28:02.2974670Z 
2017-09-22T18:28:02.3287159Z 
2017-09-22T18:28:02.9536971Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.
2017-09-22T18:28:02.9693206Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Telemetry
2017-09-22T18:28:02.9693206Z ##[section]Async Command End: Telemetry
2017-09-22T18:28:02.9693206Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Telemetry
2017-09-22T18:28:02.9693206Z ##[section]Async Command End: Telemetry
2017-09-22T18:28:02.9693206Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Telemetry
2017-09-22T18:28:02.9693206Z ##[section]Async Command End: Telemetry
2017-09-22T18:28:02.9693206Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Telemetry
2017-09-22T18:28:02.9693206Z ##[section]Async Command End: Telemetry
2017-09-22T18:28:02.9693206Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testAssemblies`

Comment: What test framework are you using? Is your test project referencing the appropriate test runner for that test framework?

Comment: I am using NUnit 3.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the appropriate test adapter as a NuGet package. For NUnit, the [NUnit Test Adapter](https://nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter) is what you're after.

Comment: Am I suppose to add this adapter to my project?

Comment: @Sameer You add it as a reference via NuGet, then make sure NuGet references are restored during your build process.

Comment: Hi I'm having the same issue, however I'm just using the default Visual Studio test framework. Do I need to reference an Test Adapter as well?